# Закрытие всех блоков с определенным классом при клике на другие элементы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При клике на кнопку открывается блок с разными элементами внутри. При клике на что-либо другое (за исключением открытого блока или его дочерних элементов) он должен закрываться обратно и все блоки с таким классом должны закрываться.

Пробую вот так:

```js
document.onclick = function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if ($(target).className != 'absraspoptionsd' && $(target).className != 'optionsmblock') {
    $('.absraspoptionsd').hide();
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="$('#sciedopt11').toggle(150);" class="optionsmblock"><span>Настройка</span></div>

<div class="absraspoptionsd" id="sciedopt11">
  <form method="post">
    <select name="item">
      <option value="noting">None</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Но этот код работает не корректно, допустим при клике на дочерние элементы зачастую тоже срабатывает скрывание блоков, как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: достаточно посмотреть, что в Вашем случае является `event.target`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/target) ссылается на объект, который вызвал событие, в Вашем случае это `select` или `form`(если нажмете рядом с `select`), соответственно для кнопки это `span`.
Для проверки ищем родителя элемента и делаем проверку на отсутствие допустимых родителей.

```js
document.onclick = function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (!target.closest(".absraspoptionsd") && !target.closest(".optionsmblock")) {
    $('.absraspoptionsd').hide();
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="$('#sciedopt11').toggle(150);" class="optionsmblock"><span>Настройка</span></div>

<div class="absraspoptionsd" id="sciedopt11">
  <form method="post">
    <select name="item">
      <option value="noting">None</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

**UPD** *вариант на jquery*

```js
$(document).on("click", function(event){
 var target = event.target;
 if(target.closest(".optionsmblock"))
 {
   $('#sciedopt11').toggle(150);
 }
 else if(!target.closest(".absraspoptionsd"))
 {
   $('.absraspoptionsd').hide();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="optionsmblock"><span>Настройка</span></div>

<div class="absraspoptionsd" id="sciedopt11">
  <form method="post">
    <select name="item">
      <option value="noting">None</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Использовать свойство `onclick` - мягко говоря не здорово. А уж смешивание jQuery с inline JS - вообще за гранью. Это я к чему: хорошо бы в ответе весь код автора привести в порядок, а не только проверку

Comment: @Regent смешивать не есть хорошо, правда и разница невелика. добавили вариант на jquery, для js нужно анимацию отдельно прописывать, если автору будет нужно напишет сам или задаст вопрос.

Comment: А я и не предлагал всё в один обработчик заталкивать, если вы об этом. Речь была про замену на `$(document).on("click"` и на `$(".optionsmblock").on("click"` соответственно, дабы `onclick` не проскакивал ни в HTML, ни в JS

Comment: @Regent только для данного случая - зачем два обработчика, когда можно использовать 1 ? да и букв поменьше)